# apache-commons-matrix for clojure not playing well with core.matrix?

Tags: clojure, apache-commons-math

I'm trying to use https://github.com/adereth/apache-commons-matrix to
access the functionality of Apache Commons Math, via the Maven repo
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 .

My main guide is Matt Adereth's
http://adereth.github.io/blog/2013/11/08/core-dot-matrix-plus-apache-commons-math/
, from 2013!?  Surprise, surprise, there seems to have been some code
rot.  Several issues in particular:

1. The code in the mvn repo is missing an extension `(extend-protocol mp/PMatrixMultiply)` present in the github repo here
   https://github.com/adereth/apache-commons-matrix/blob/ef1e2bccbee7f8b8f5d9fbfdfe7639c23f6c406f/src/apache_commons_matrix/core.clj#L192 ?
2. Matt's guide suggests using `(m/set-current-implementation   :apache-commons)`, but
   `clojure.core.matrix.implementations/KNOWN-IMPLEMENTATIONS` has as
   its entry `:commons-math apache-commons-matrix.core`
3. But `(m/set-current-implementation :commons-math)` throws a
   different error:

   ```
    Error loading core.matrix implementation:  apache-commons-matrix.core
    #error {
    :cause Too many arguments to throw, throw expects a single Throwable instance
    :via
    [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
    :message Syntax error compiling throw at (apache_commons_matrix/core.clj:19:13).
    :data #:clojure.error{:phase :compile-syntax-check, :line 19, :column 13, :source apache_commons_matrix/core.clj, :symbol throw}
    :at [clojure.lang.Compiler analyzeSeq Compiler.java 7132]}
   ```

   indeed, the referenced line uses what looks like a bad call to
   clojure' `(throw)`:

   ```
    (throw (ex-info "Apache Commons Math matrices only supports up to 2 dimensions") {:requested-shape dims})
   ```

anyone trying to make this potentially useful interop work?

Comment: if linear algebra is what you need I suggest looking at dtype-next and neanderthal which are well-maintained and fast

Comment: Another option, [denisovan](https://github.com/cailuno/denisovan) is a core.matrix implementation backed by [Neanderthal](https://neanderthal.uncomplicate.org/).

Comment: Good thoughts, and i've used neaderthal on x86 hardware.  i'm looking for a solution that works on the M1/arm64.

Comment: For a simple, pure-java solution, I would also suggest looking at JAMA:  https://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/